# BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '1'-working properly in local but not in remote server

Tags: spring-mvc

> ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag 
>   Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '1'
>   available as request attribute
>
> [tomcat-http--30] ERROR
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag - Neither
>   BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '1' available as
>   request attribute 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither
>   BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '1' available as
>   request attribute
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)

In my jsp page or controller there is no bean  '1'

jsp page :

```
<form:hidden path="${employerForm.companyUser.uid}"/>
                        <form:form id="employerForm" action="saveCompanyInfo"
                            method="post" commandName="employerForm" role="form">
```

In Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/employer/addCompanyProfile",
            "/admin/addCompanyProfile" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createEmployerProfile(@RequestParam("user") String username,
            Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Its is working properly in my local, Getting error in remote server

Comment: In local tried with same war file and database , but still exception not getting in local , Exception found In remote server oly

Comment: Is it a typo or is the `<form:input>` tag **before** the `<form:form>` one ? And it is at least *uncommon* to have a dynamic path for a field ... The common way would be : `<form:hidden path="employerForm.companyUser.uid"/>`

Comment: oh!! yea.. I din notice it.. thank you so much. It works !! :)

Comment: It was working in local because the page cache was not cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain how it can work in local, but I think you did not want to have a dynamic path for your field. You should write :

```
<form:hidden path="employerForm.companyUser.uid"/>
```